# Prolog goal always fails unexpectedly

Tags: prolog

For a school project, I want to construct a scheduler for processing tasks. Since it's my first time using Prolog, I encountered some difficulties; even after searching a while for a solution.

The execution_schedule_checker(...) rule is calling the process_schedule_of_core(...) with a list of functors as follows:

```
[schedule(c1, [t1, t6, t7]), schedule(c2, [t2, t3, t4, t5])]
```

Here are the declared facts:

```
core(c1).
core(c2).

task(t1).
task(t2).
...

execution_schedule_checker([schedule(Core, Tasks) | RestSchedules ], ListOfCores, ListOfTasks, ListProcessedTasks, ListProcessedCores) :- 
    process_schedule_of_core(Core, Tasks, ListProcessedTasks, ListProcessedCores, ListProcessedTasksAcc),
    execution_schedule_checker(RestSchedules, ListOfCores, ListOfTasks, ListProcessedTasksAcc, ListProcessedCores).

process_schedule_of_core(Core , [], ListProcessedTasks , [Core| _], ListProcessedTasks).
process_schedule_of_core(Core, [Task | RestTasks], ListProcessedTasksAcc , ListProcessedCores, ListProcessedTasks) :-
    process_schedule_of_core(Core, RestTasks, [Task | ListProcessedTasksAcc], ListProcessedCores, ListProcessedTasks).
```

Everything works correctly until the end of the second schedule is reached. It fails, and the program stops.

Like I said before, it's my first time using Prolog. So my apologies if the code is not correct or can be optimised.

Comment: Please show what query you are trying to test.

Comment: execution_schedule_checker([schedule(c1,[t1,t6,t7]),schedule(c2,[t2,t3,t4,t5])] , [c1, c2], [t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7], ListProcessedTasks, ListProcessedCores).

Comment: Now can you explain what this is trying to do, and how it is trying to do it?  And why you bother defining `task()` and `core()`, since they don't get used anywhere?

Comment: In this code, i'm just trying to put all the processed tasks in the ListProcessedTasksAcc, and all the processed cores in the ListProcessedCores. It's just an 'append' like function. I continually put the task in the list, until the empty list is reached, then the core is added to the list processed cores. That's what is happening in `process_schedule_of_core()`. `core()` and `task()` are used elsewhere in the program, but they just define a core and a task (example: core(c1) with c1 is a unique identifier).

Comment: That's the "how", not the "what".  It sounds like you want to gather all of the tasks and cores in the list of schedules and make sure that every task and core appears exactly once.

Comment: Yes, that's it. The problem is that in the first line of `process_schedule_of_core()`, where we deal the empty list, it fails because of the fourth parameter `[Core| _] `. It expects that the head of the list is Core, which is true for the first schedule, but not for the second one, since it has a different core. I just needed to add this Core in my accumulator.

Answer (score 1):

You never defined what `execution_schedule_checker` should do if the list of schedules is empty.

Assuming that you are "checking" that all cores and tasks appear exactly once across the schedules, this should do:

```
% execution_schedule_checker(S,C,T) is true if the schedules in S use all cores in C and tasks in T exactly once
execution_schedule_checker( [], [], [] ).
execution_schedule_checker( [schedule(Core, Tasks)|Schedules], UnusedCores, UnusedTasks ) :-
    split1( Core, UnusedCores, StillUnusedCores ),
    split( Tasks, UnusedTasks, StillUnusedTasks ),
    execution_schedule_checker( Schedules, StillUnusedCores, StillUnusedTasks ).

% split( L1, L2, L3 ) is true if append( L1, L2, L12 ) and L12 is a permutation of L3
split( [], L, L ).
split( [H|T], L1, L3 ) :-
    split1( H, L1, L2 ),
    split( T, L2, L3 ).

% split1( A, L1, L2 ) === split( [A], L1, L2 )
split1( X, [X|T], T ).
split1( X, [H|T], [H|T2] ) :-
    split1( X, T, T2 ).
```

Comment: `execution_schedule_checker([], ListOfCores, ListOfTasks, ListProcessedTasks, ListProcessedCores) :-
 length(ListProcessedTasks, Lpt),
 length(ListProcessedCores, Lpc),
 length(ListOfTasks, Lot),
 length(ListOfCores, Loc),
 Lpt = Lot,
 Lpc = Loc.`

The problem appears when the first line of `process_schedule_of_core()` is called.

Comment: When the empty list is reached.

Comment: `execution_schedule_checker` doesn't call `process_schedule_of_core` when the list is empty (the code you just posted).

Comment: That is my intention. If the list is empty, it means that no more schedules/tasks/cores have to be processed.

Comment: "The problem appears when the first line of `process_schedule_of_core* is called when the empty list is reached."  But if it doesn't get called, how can it cause any problems?

Comment: It is called, since the first line of the body of `execution_schedule_checker` calls `process_schedule_of_core`. The problem appears when `process_schedule_of_core` is called with [schedule(c1, [t1, t6, t7]), **schedule(c2, [t2, t3, t4, t5])**]. `[Core| _]` (the 4th parameter in `process_schedule_of_core`) expects Core to be c2 but is in fact c1. So it fails.

Comment: Maybe I should explain the rule posted above. I just want to compare the the lengths of all the available cores `ListOfCores` with all the processed cores in the list `ListProcessedCores` (the same for the tasks). I hope that the program fails when a core has not been processed, this can happen when, for example, I have cores c1, c2, c3 available but only two schedules are given (like here: [schedule(c1, [t1, t6, t7]), schedule(c2, [t2, t3, t4, t5])]). Each core **must** have a schedule, even if the list of tasks is empty. The same for tasks. Nevertheless,it returns always true (strange).